# Determine if a given set is a subspace of vector space of matrices of third order

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $S=\Bigg\{ A \in M_3(\mathbb{R}): \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \in R(A) \Bigg\} $ Determine if S is a subspace of  vector space of matrices of third order.

The fact that I know one vector that belongs to the image of matrix $A$ doesn't help me very much unless I prove that for every matrix that has $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ in R(A) if I multiply it by a constant this vector would still be in R(A) and if I multiply it by the matrix that is also in the set S their product still remains in S. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every subspace of a vector space $V$ must contain the zero vector. Does $S$ contain the zero matrix?

Comment: I see, zero matrix cannot be the element of S since it's columns can't represent this vector [1 1 1] no matter which constants we take and since zero vector isn't element of S, then S isn't subset.

Comment: You mean $S$ isn't a subspace, but yes that's right.